# changing/creating documents ids in itext 5.4.3

Tags: java, itext

I'm using itext 5.4.3 version to edit the pdf document. It works like charm for set of documents, but for some it is failing. I did the analysis and found issue is occurring due to missing bits in trailer. Itext is expecting 32bit trailer information, but some of the documents, trailer information not exists inturn throwing this exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.createInfoId(PdfEncryption.java:558)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:383)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:337)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper.close(PdfStamper.java:206)
```

Is there a way to create the document id forcefully before save and closing the stamper? I know 5.5.7 version will fix this issue, but just a thought whether can we make this work in 5.4.3 version itself? I tried this approach but no luck.

Comment: If you're a customer of iText group, customer support can help you. If you're a non-paying user, using iText under the AGPL, then you should either upgrade or fix the problem yourself. Note that if you're using iText under the AGPL, you should also obey the obligations of the AGPL. If you're using iText in the context of a Cognizant project for a customer, you probably should purchase a commercial license. If you already have a commercial license, please contact your account manager at iText Software Asia Pte. Ltd.

Comment: Since this is a problem that can no longer be produced in more recent version of iText (it was a bug; it has been fixed now), this question is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: I agree this problem is resolved in recent most version. However, is there a way to create the document id forcefully in itext 5.4.3 version?